# Change product image by clicking on swatch - Shopify

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, liquid

I am trying to change the product image on my shopify page when clicking on a swatch. But I can't get it to work...

This is the code I wrote (I'm sorry if it is elementary):

```
<div class="product grid__item {{ grid_item_width }} slide-up-animation 
animated" role="listitem">
  <a href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}" class="product__image" 
    title="{{ product.title | escape }}">
    <img class="theImage" src="{{ product.featured_image.src | img_url: 'grande' 
}}" alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt | escape }}">
  </a>

<div class="product__title text-center">
  <a href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}">{{ product.title }}</a>
</div>

{% if settings.vendor_show %}
<div class="product__vendor text-center">
  {{ product.vendor }}
</div>
{% endif %}    

<!-- COLOR SWATCH -->
<script>
theButton.onclick = function pictureChange()
{
  document.getElementsByClassName("theImage").src="{{% assign featured_image = current_variant.featured_image %}}";
}
</script>
<div class="product__prices text-center">
{% for option in product.options %}
 {% if option == 'Color' %}
  {% assign index = forloop.index0 %}
  {% assign colorlist = '' %}
  {% assign color = '' %}
  {% for variant in product.variants %}
    {% capture color %}{{ variant.options[index] }}{% endcapture %}
    {% unless colorlist contains color %}
      <img class="theButton" src="{{ color | downcase | append: '.gif' | asset_url }}" alt="{{ color }}" width="16" height="16" onclick="pictureChange()" />
      {% capture tempList %}{{colorlist | append: color | append: ‘ ‘}}{% endcapture %}
      {% assign colorlist = tempList %}
    {% endunless %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %} 
<br/>
```

Does anybody have some pointers?

When I open up the console, it says that 'theButton is not defined'.

Thank you, please help!

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing this issue and have sorted this for my store. As the shopify changed its structure(sectioned themes), many have facing the problem with `selectCallback` function. Please follow the below steps for adding the swatches in the sectioned themes -

1. Create the `swatch.liquid` file in the snippet. Copy the below code in it -

   ```
   {% comment %}
     Set the extension of your color files below. Use 'png', 'jpeg', 'jpg' or 'gif'.
   {% endcomment %}

   {% assign file_extension = 'png' %}

   {% if swatch == blank %}
   <div class="swatch error">
     <p>You must include the snippet swatch.liquid with the name of a product option.</p> 
     <p>Use: <code>{% raw %}{% include 'swatch' with 'name of your product option here' %}{% endraw %}</code></p>
     <p>Example: <code>{% raw %}{% include 'swatch' with 'Color' %}{% endraw %}</code></p>
   </div>
   {% else %}

   {% assign found_option = false %}
   {% assign is_color = false %}
   {% assign option_index = 0 %}

   {% for option in product.options %}
     {% if option == swatch %}
       {% assign found_option = true %}
       {% assign option_index = forloop.index0 %}
       <style>
         label[for="product-select-option-{{ option_index }}"] { display: none; }
         #product-select-option-{{ option_index }} { display: none; }
         #product-select-option-{{ option_index }} + .custom-style-select-box { display: none !important; }
       </style>
       <script>jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery('.selector-wrapper:eq({{ option_index }})').hide(); });</script>
       {% assign downcased_option = swatch | downcase %}
       {% if downcased_option contains 'color' or downcased_option contains 'colour' %}
         {% assign is_color = true %}
       {% endif %}
     {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}

   {% unless found_option %}
   <div class="swatch error">
     <p>You included the snippet swatch.liquid with the name of a product option — <code>'{{ swatch }}'</code> — that does not belong to your product.</p>
     <p>Use <code>{% raw %}{% include 'swatch' with 'name of your product option here' %}{% endraw %}</code></p>
     <p>Example: <code>{% raw %}{% include 'swatch' with 'Color' %}{% endraw %}</code></p>
     <p><strong>This is case-sensitive!</strong> Do not put in <code>'color'</code> if your product option name is <code>'Color'</code>.</p>
   </div>
   {% else %}
   <div class="swatch clearfix" data-option-index="{{ option_index }}">
     <div class="header">{{ swatch }}</div>
     {% assign values = '' %}
     {% for variant in product.variants %}
       {% assign value = variant.options[option_index] %}
       {% unless values contains value %}
         {% assign values = values | join: ',' %}
         {% assign values = values | append: ',' | append: value %} 
         {% assign values = values | split: ',' %}
         <div data-value="{{ value | escape }}" class="swatch-element {% if is_color %}color {% endif %}{{ value | handle }} {% if variant.available %}available{% else %}soldout{% endif %}">
           {% if is_color %}
           <div class="tooltip">{{ value }}</div>
           {% endif %}
           <input id="swatch-{{ option_index }}-{{ value | handle }}" type="radio" name="option-{{ option_index }}" value="{{ value | escape }}"{% if forloop.first %} checked{% endif %} {% unless variant.available %}disabled{% endunless %} />
           {% if is_color %}
           <label for="swatch-{{ option_index }}-{{ value | handle }}" style="background-color: {{ value | split: ' ' | last | handle }}; background-image: url({{ value | handle | append: '.' | append: file_extension | asset_url }})">
             <img class="crossed-out" src="{{ 'soldout.png' | asset_url }}" />
           </label>
           {% else %}
           <label for="swatch-{{ option_index }}-{{ value | handle }}">
             {{ value }}
             <img class="crossed-out" src="{{ 'soldout.png' | asset_url }}" />
           </label>
           {% endif %}
         </div>
       {% endunless %}
       {% if variant.available %}
       <script>
         jQuery('.swatch[data-option-index="{{ option_index }}"] .{{ value | handle }}').removeClass('soldout').addClass('available').find(':radio').removeAttr('disabled');
       </script>
       {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
   </div>

   {% endunless %}

   {% endif %}
   ```
2. Now add the jquery code in `theme.liquid` file in `<script>` tag just above the close `</body>` tag at the bottom. See the code below -

   ```
       jQuery(function() {
         jQuery('.swatch :radio').change(function() {
           var optionIndex = jQuery(this).closest('.swatch').attr('data-option-index');
           var optionValue = jQuery(this).val();
           jQuery(this)
           .closest('form')
           .find('.single-option-selector')
           .eq(optionIndex)
           .val(optionValue)
           .trigger('change');
         });

         jQuery('.single-option-selector').change(function() {
           var optionValue = jQuery(this).val();
           jQuery(this).closest('form').find('.swatch').each(function( index ) {
             jQuery(this).find(':radio').each(function( index ) {
               if(jQuery(this).val() == optionValue ){
                 $(this).siblings(':radio').prop('checked', false);
                   $(this).prop('checked', true);     
               }   
             });
           });
         });
       });
   ```
3. Now add the jquery code in the `product-template.liquid` section just above the `{% schema %}`. See the code below -

   ```
   {% if product.variants.size > 1 %}
       <script>
         var variantImages = {},
           thumbnails,
           variant,
           variantImage,
           optionValue,
           productOptions = [];
           {% for variant in product.variants %}
              variant = {{ variant | json }};
              if ( typeof variant.featured_image !== 'undefined' && variant.featured_image !== null ) {
                variantImage =  variant.featured_image.src.split('?')[0].replace(/http(s)?:/,'');
                variantImages[variantImage] = variantImages[variantImage] || {};
                {% for option in product.options %}

                  {% assign option_value = variant.options[forloop.index0] %}
                  {% assign option_key = 'option-' | append: forloop.index0 %}

                  if (typeof variantImages[variantImage][{{ option_key | json }}] === 'undefined') {
                    variantImages[variantImage][{{ option_key | json }}] = {{ option_value | json }};
                  }
                  else {
                    var oldValue = variantImages[variantImage][{{ option_key | json }}];
                    if ( oldValue !== null && oldValue !== {{ option_value | json }} )  {
                      variantImages[variantImage][{{ option_key | json }}] = null;
                    }
                  }
                {% endfor %}
              }
              productOptions.push(variant);
           {% endfor %}
       </script> 
       {% endif %}
   ```
4. Now include the swatches in the `product-template.liquid` section in the form just below the `</select>` field -

   ```
   {% if product.available and product.variants.size > 1 %}
                 {% for option in product.options %}
                   {% include 'swatch' with option %}
                 {% endfor %}
               {% endif %}
   ```
5. Last step is to add css for the swatches. Add the css into `theme.scss.liquid` -

   /* 
       Swatches Styles
       */

   ```
   {% assign width = '50px' %}
   {% assign height = '35px' %}
   .swatch { 
     margin:1em 0; 
     width: 100%;
     display: inline-block;
   }
   /* Label */
   .swatch .header {
     margin: 0.5em 0;
   }
   /* Hide radio buttons.*/
   .swatch input { 
     display:none;
   }
   .swatch label {
     /* Rounded corners */
     -webkit-border-radius:2px;
     -moz-border-radius:2px;
     border-radius:2px;
     /* To give width and height */
     float:left;
     /* Color swatches contain no text so they need to have a width. */
     min-width:{{ width }} !important; 
     height:{{ height }} !important;
     /* No extra spacing between them */
     margin:0;
     /* The border when the button is not selected */
     border:#ccc 1px solid;
     /* Background color */
     background-color:#ddd;
     /* Styling text */
     font-size:13px;
     text-align:center;
     line-height:{{ height }};
     white-space:nowrap;
     text-transform:uppercase;
   }
   .swatch-element label { padding:0 10px; }
   .color.swatch-element label { padding:0; }
   /* Styling selected swatch */
   /* Slightly raised */
   .swatch input:checked + label {
     -webkit-box-shadow:0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
     -moz-box-shadow:0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
     box-shadow:0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
     border-color:transparent;
   } 
   .swatch .swatch-element {
     float:left;
     -webkit-transform:translateZ(0); /* webkit flicker fix */
     -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased; /* webkit text rendering fix */
     /* Spacing between buttons */
     margin:0px 10px 10px 0;
     /* To position the sold out graphic and tooltip */
     position:relative;
   }
   .color.swatch-element label {
     padding: 0;
     min-width: 40px !important;
     height: 40px !important;
     border-radius: 100%;
   }
   /* Image with the cross in it */
   .crossed-out { position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; left:0; top:0; }
   .swatch .swatch-element .crossed-out { display:none; }
   .swatch .swatch-element.soldout .crossed-out { display:block; }
   .swatch .swatch-element.soldout label {
     filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* internet explorer */
     -khtml-opacity: 0.6;      /* khtml, old safari */
     -moz-opacity: 0.6;       /* mozilla, netscape */
     opacity: 0.6;           /* fx, safari, opera */
   }
   /* Tooltips */
   .swatch .tooltip {
     text-align:center;
     background:gray;
     color:#fff;
     bottom:100%;
     padding: 10px;
     display:block;
     position:absolute;
     width:100px;
     left:{{ width | remove: 'px' | to_number | divided_by: 2 | minus: 50 | plus: 2 }}px;
     margin-bottom:15px;
     /* Make it invisible by default */
     filter:alpha(opacity=0);
     -khtml-opacity: 0;
     -moz-opacity: 0;
     opacity:0;
     visibility:hidden;
     /* Animations */
     -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
     -moz-transform: translateY(10px);
     -ms-transform: translateY(10px);
     -o-transform: translateY(10px);
     transform: translateY(10px);
     -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all .25s ease-out;
     -ms-transition: all .25s ease-out;
     -o-transition: all .25s ease-out;
     transition: all .25s ease-out;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
     -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
     -ms-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
     -o-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
     box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
     z-index: 10000;
     -moz-box-sizing:border-box; 
     -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; 
     box-sizing:border-box;
   }
   .swatch .tooltip:before {
     bottom:-20px;
     content:" ";
     display:block;
     height:20px;
     left:0;
     position:absolute;
     width:100%;
   }
   /* CSS triangle */
   .swatch .tooltip:after {
     border-left:solid transparent 10px;
     border-right:solid transparent 10px;
     border-top:solid gray 10px;
     bottom:-10px;
     content:" ";
     height:0;
     left:50%;
     margin-left:-13px;
     position:absolute;
     width:0;
   }
   .swatch .swatch-element:hover .tooltip {
     filter:alpha(opacity=100);
     -khtml-opacity:1;
     -moz-opacity:1;
     opacity:1;
     visibility:visible;
     -webkit-transform:translateY(0px);
     -moz-transform:translateY(0px);
     -ms-transform:translateY(0px);
     -o-transform:translateY(0px);
     transform:translateY(0px);
   }
   .swatch.error {
     background-color:#E8D2D2!important;
     color:#333!important;
     padding:1em;
     border-radius:5px;
   }
   .swatch.error p {
     margin:0.7em 0;
   }
   .swatch.error p:first-child {
     margin-top:0;
   }
   .swatch.error p:last-child {
     margin-bottom:0;
   }
   .swatch.error code {
     font-family:monospace;
   }
   .product-form__cart-submit {
     width: auto;
     padding-left: 30px;
     padding-right: 30px;
   }

   .swatch .color.swatch-element input:checked+label {
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,1);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,1);
     box-shadow: 0px 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,1);
   }
   ```

Comment: I got this semi-working - On the product page it works perfectly! However, I was hoping to use this not on the product page but on the pages as the customer is browsing. I originally had swatches, but I noticed through a heatmap people were clicking on them to see variations before clicking on the product.